# Cannot install Jetbrains ReSharper. Installer is blank and silence installation doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2015, jetbrains-ide, resharper-9.0

Hello smart people from stackoverflow

I own an copy of the JetBrain Suite including [JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). I've already installed it on my Laptop but whatever I try - it's not working on my Windows 7 PC where I do 99%+ of my programming.

I tried running as admin and in every compatibility properity windows has to offer. I right clicked on the `JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2015.1.3.exe` and confirmed the licensor. I also downloaded the SHA-256 checksum and tried to install it (which was stupid because it doesn't seem to be anything to install). I redownloaded the installer multiple times and I also did a reinstall of Visual Studio itself.

When I tried running the silence installation it just did nothing. I didn't even get an error response.

I currently have Visual Studio 2015 installed. *(14.0.23107.0 D14REL)*

I also contacted the JetBrains support but when I stated that I'm a student using the student discount they just silenced.

I love how ReSharper enhances Visual Studio but I somehow cannot get the installer working. Whenever I open it there's just a plain blank form. It showed its visuals without problems on my Laptop.
I suspect that the visuals are there but not visible (or completely white) because when I click at the upper right corner it closes as if the X was still there.
I do not provide an screenshot because it's just a completely white square without header and everything.

I suspect that they are using some windows resources that I don't have installed for some reason. I've double checked Windows Update - I have everything installed.

I tried everything I could think of. Maybe someone of you guys is able of helping me.

Thanks. Have a nice day

Comment: try RC3 of 9.2: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+9.2+EAP

Comment: RC3 doesnt work neither. But thanks to your comment i was able to resolve it myself. The installer suddenly worked once i copied it onto my desktop. I have absolutely no clue why the installer works this way but thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

The installer works fine once i removed it out of my cluttered download folder

I ran various tests and I'm pretty sure that i found the root to the problem.

The installer stops working when It's together with an .dll file called d3d9.dll. It's an .dll file that belongs to DirectX.

An exact copy of the file I have inside my download folder can be found here:

- [Mirror 1](http://www.xup.in/dl,61652710/d3d9.dll/)
- [Mirror 2](https://mega.nz/#F!U01DWTxT!JtrE2kd-yIu3poJu9dWoIw)
- [Mirror 3](http://www.mediafire.com/download/z0flokhvobekz9l/d3d9.dll)

I've run enough tests to be sure that it is exactly this .dll file.
[I have reported this to the JetBrains Team](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-446977)

Comment: This is something you should inform Jetbrains about, at support@jetbrains.com, they would probably like to know about this problem. In my experience with emailing support, they usually respond pretty quick. If you think you have information to just open up a bug issue in their issue tracker, you should [go here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FRSRP), log in, and then create a new issue.

Comment: Off the top of my head. Some browsers, internet explorer included, tags files as "Downloaded from the internet". Opening up such a file will run it with reduced access rights, could this be the culprit? Please try right-clicking the original file in your Downloads directory and picking "Properties", the seeing if there are some funky stuff near the bottom of the dialog box along these lines, and then if you can remove this "Downloaded from the internet" flag, does the installer then appear to work?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I tought about that one too. But when I copy it to my desktop it works fine and when I copy it back it doesnt work again. It makes no sense to me thst the vrowser should store that information somewhere else when not the file meta data but the meta would be cooied to when copying or moving the file. I downloaded via Mozilla Firefox